# div float left.... when it wraps, it wraps all funky

Tags: css, html

i have between 1 and 10 floating divs. If i'm showing 1-5 or all 10, they show up fine:

item1 item2 item3 item4 item5

item6 item7 item8 item9 item10

but if i show like 7 of them, they start getting all weird:

item1 item2 item3 item4 item5

```
                     item6
```

item7

How do i fix this? here's what the div code looks like:

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right:4px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center; padding:7px; color:#0066a4; font-size: smaller; width:100px;">
  <a href="#" onclick="getElectronicServiceCopy('10'); return false;"><img src="/images/images/Icons/Vehicle_Green.png" border="0"></a>
  <br>Vehicle
</div>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: can you fix your code block formatting? I don't think it's showing up like you intended..

Comment: I think we need more of your code. I just put together a quick fiddle with multiple divs, using the code you provided, and it looks fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/F9qFQ/

Comment: Working fine here, so the problem is with the parts of the code you're not showing. Sandeep may be on to something.

Comment: i tried it as well: http://jsfiddle.net/p3t3B/ and it shows fine, but it doesn't always work out that way. I've seen this before and i always resort back to tables. I'm just trying to avoid that this time.

Comment: Use Bootstrap's grid system and you will never have this problem again http://getbootstrap.com/. "Resorting to tables" is not OK and you should feel bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i saw you code may be you have to define `height` to your **floated** DIV.

For example:

```
div{
 height:200px;
}
```